# align 2 elements left and right bootstrap issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Iam trying to achieve this positioning effect which is on the picture. Text from the left with some padding bottom and top for the text and position absolute for the image on the right side but i cannot achive it properly. Any suggestions ?

[image]

I will share my code here

```css
.luma-founders { position: relative; padding: 30px 0; background: #8bc541; }
.luma-founders h3 { font-family: "Questrial", sans-serif; font-size: 36px; color: #fff; margin: 79px 0 40px 0; padding: 0 11px; }
.luma-founders p { font-family: "Raleway-Regular", sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 30px; color: #fff; padding: 0 11px; }
.luma-crew { position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;  }
.luma-crew img { min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; height: auto; width: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="luma-founders">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>Who is Luma Comfort</h3>
          <p>We at Luma Comfort want the best for you. We pride ourselves as innovators in design and functionality, to ensure that you have the best quality products to choose from.</p>
          <p>Our philosophy is that comfort doesn't just come from how well our products work, but how good they make you feel to look at them in your home or office. Luma Comfort knows the importance of quality products that look beautiful too.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- col-md-6 -->
        <div class="luma-crew">
          <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/p5pxb0r95/founders.jpg" width="783" height="510" title="someText" alt="someText">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- row -->
    </div>
    <!-- container -->
```

Comment: I'm added an answer ,if it's help full please tick it ,else  reply the remaining problem

Comment: Something like this? http://www.bootply.com/ZWP9aInrUe

Comment: @LuukSkeur , Yes like that and is there any way to make it responsive somehow ?

Comment: Most of it is responsive, only thing on mobile is that you have to make the image 100% width and no margin on it. @noone432423

Answer (score 0):

added some margin for `.luma-crew img`  (ie, margin-left: 100%;)

```css
.luma-founders { position: relative; padding: 30px 0; background: #8bc541; }
.luma-founders h3 { font-family: "Questrial", sans-serif; font-size: 36px; color: #fff; margin: 79px 0 40px 0; padding: 0 11px; }
.luma-founders p { font-family: "Raleway-Regular", sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 30px; color: #fff; padding: 0 11px; }
.luma-crew { position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;  }
.luma-crew img { min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; /*height: auto; width: auto;*/  margin-left: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="luma-founders">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>Who is Luma Comfort</h3>
          <p>We at Luma Comfort want the best for you. We pride ourselves as innovators in design and functionality, to ensure that you have the best quality products to choose from.</p>
          <p>Our philosophy is that comfort doesn't just come from how well our products work, but how good they make you feel to look at them in your home or office. Luma Comfort knows the importance of quality products that look beautiful too.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- col-md-6 -->
        <div class="luma-crew">
          <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/p5pxb0r95/founders.jpg" width="783" height="510" title="someText" alt="someText">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- row -->
    </div>
    <!-- container -->
```

Comment: sorry but the whole idea is that the green background to be full width with 6 col div wrapping the text and from the left side this crew image which must be same height as the green background and should be position:absolute; left: 50%; right:0; left:0; and bottom:0; but on my example the image is leaking over the green background and Iam trying to figure out how to position it correctly